# Functions are not called from recursive functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

```js
function and(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return true;
  }

  const head = arr[0];
  const tail = arr.slice(1);

  return head && and(tail);
}

and([true, true, false]);
```

I have this recursion called 4 times and at the end

```js
if (arr.length === 0) {
    return true;
  }
```

I thought it would end with

However, the function has only been called 3 times !!

```js
head: [true]    tail: [true,false]
head: [true]    tail: [false]
head: [false]   tail: []
```

This is the result I checked

```js
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return true;
  }
```

This condition didn't even work.

I need help.

Sorry for using the translator

Comment: change ```return head && and(tail);``` to ```return and(tail);```.

Comment: @cybercoder Then the function would be guaranteed to return `true`, which goes against the whole point of the function.

Comment: @Aplet123 the question is about count of calling happens in recursion! So he/she have to change the body of function to achieve correct answer. I made a comment to guide not an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript and many other languages, [`&&` is short-circuiting](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-ff22b2f5608c). This means that if you have `a && f()`, and `a` is `false`, the condition is already known to be false, so `f` is never ran. Since the head of your array is `false` in the third call, the `&&` operator will short-circuit and return false without even continuing the recursion. If you try `and([true, true, true])` you will notice that it **does** go all the way to a 0-length array and your condition **will** do something.